# Variable name of Form Repeater

Tags: php

I have a form that inside the form have Form Repeater Jquery. Each of input have a variable name like 'faultreport' etc. and then variable name of Form Repeater is 'actioncode','repaircode','compos','compart'. so before i'm inserting into Database, I'm showing the $_POST data using **print_r($_POST)**
this is the result :

[image]

code for showing array data :

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['Save'])) {
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

then I want to get **value** that variable name of Form Repeater. Already tried this :

> 1. echo $_POST['**list[0]actioncode**'];
> 2. echo $_POST['**listactioncode[0]**'];
> 3. echo $_POST['**actioncode[0]**'];
> 4. echo $_POST['**[0]actioncode**'];
> 5. echo $_POST['**actioncode**'];

the result always (Undefined array key "actioncode"). How did i get that variable name?

**EDIT**
Solve using this code :

```
print_r($_POST["list"]["0"]["actioncode"]);
```

and show the actual value of actioncode = **1**

Comment: Absolute language _basics_ you are asking about here. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$list =  $_POST['list'];

$inner = $list[0]['actioncode'];
```

Comment: i try this but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you attach the code in stead of image please?

Comment: already attached code